# How to parse new line from HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

When i am parsing a HTML file using jsoup, texts in multiple lines (with `< br />`) in the HTML file is presented as a single line without new lines(`\n`). How i can parse the multi line HTML document as multiline strings ??

I am using the method: `Element.text()`

Eg:

HTML contains C code which is properly displayed in multiple lines in HtMl file, but when i am taking the text data, all the data are presented in a single line without new line charactors.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `<br />` with something else and back, like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ejemplo.html").get(); //Here included the <br>'s
String temp = doc.html().replace("<br />", "$$$"); //$$$ instead <br>
doc = Jsoup.parse(temp); //Parse again

String text = doc.body().text().replace("$$$", "\n").toString()); //example
//I get back the new lines (\n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` method of Element (and `TextNode`) calls `appendWhitespaceIfBr(...)` which will replace every `<br />` (or whitespace) with a blank. Unfortunately i see no mechanism for turning this off without working on the code.

But maybe you can try replacing all `<br />` Tags with a new subclass of `Node`.